# Rails view helpers in helper file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm probably missing something obvious here but here's what I'm trying to do.

From the view, I'm calling a custom helper function

```
<div>
  <%=display_services%>
</div>
```

In the helper file with the display_services function

```
def display_services
  html = "<div>"
  form_for @user do |f|
   f.text_field ...
  end
 html << "</div>"
end
```

I find that form_for method and f.text_field output directly to HTML stream without the div wrapper that I like. What is the proper syntax to output all the HTML in display_services? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just a suggestion for style, I like doing something like this:

In your view:

```
<% display_services %>
```

Please note that the `=` isn't needed any more.
The helper then uses `concat()` to append something to your page and the putting-long-strings-together thing is obsolete too:

```
def display_services
  concat("<div>")
  form_for @user do |f|
    f.text_field ...
  end
  concat("</div>")
end
```

Is it nessaccary to put the `<div>` tag into the helper. If you need a helper for embedding something into a block you could use some yield-magic as well:

```
def block_helper
  concat("<div>")
  yield
  concat("</div>")
end
```

And use it like this in your view - of course with helpers too:

```
<% block_helper do %>
  cool block<br/>
  <% display_services %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: One other note, if you want your HTML to look pretty, and "\n" to the end of concat.

Answer (score 32):

IMHO, you should not have HTML hardcoded in Ruby code. Instead, prefer [partials views](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html).

```
module ServicesHelper
  def display_services(user)
    render :partial => "shared/display_services", :locals => {:user => user}
  end
end
```

Comment: I agree with this approach - seems cleaner to build as little html in your helper as possible.

Comment: Although I have up-voted this answer and I wholeheartedly agree that the smallest amount of HTML possible should be generated in your helper (I would venture to say 'NO HTML SHOULD EVER BE GENERATED IN A HELPER!'), I'm wondering about the benefit of this extra level of indirection for just one line of code. Surely it just increases the time taken to understand and navigate the codebase at a later date, or by a different developer. (Although of course I can see that it would save keystrokes in the short term if it was used a lot.)

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out, I had to do something like this

```
def display_services
  html = "<div>"
  html << (form_for @user do |f|
   f.text_field ...
  end)
  html << "</div>"
end
```

Note the () wrapped around the form block. If someone has a better solution, let me know.