# Helpers in Rails - What's the best approach when building the html string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I usually write helpers that way:

```
  def bloco_vazio (texto = "", btn = "", args={})
      titulo = content_tag :h3, "Vazio!" 
      p = content_tag :p, texto
      content_tag :div, (titulo + tag(:hr) + p + btn ), args
  end
```

But i commonly see people using other approaches, like:

```
 def flash_notice
    html = ""
    unless flash.empty?
      flash.each do |f|
        html << "<div class='alert alert-#{f[:type].to_s}'>"
        html << "<a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>"
        html << f[:text].to_s
        html << "</div>"
      end
    end
    html
 end
```

or

```
def a_helper (some_text ="")
  %{ <h3>some title</h3>
      <p>#{some_text}</p>    
  }%
end
```

I used these two lasts in the past and ran into some problems then started using the content_tag and tag helpers, even that i still have to use the `.html_safe` method sometimes.

Is there a standard way to build helpers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If html is longer than 1 line, i usually put the html in a partial and call it with a custom helper method

**view**

```
<= display_my_html(@item, {html_class: "active"}) %>
```

**helper**

```
def display_my_html(item, opts={})
  name = item.name.upcase
  html_class = opts.key?(:html_class) ? opts[:html_class] : "normal"

  render "my_html", name: name, html_class: html_class
end
```

**partial**

```
<div class="<%= html_class %>">
  <span class="user">
    <%= name %>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This practice fits larger blocks.. but if i want a helper to a btn_with_icon for example. I would have to `render "application/btn_with_icon" text: "text", icon: "icon"`

Answer (score 4):

The best approach is to write ruby code in the helpers and html only on .html.erb files, even if thay are "strings", so you should use the content_tag for helpers and if you want one block you could use:

```
<%= content_tag :div, :class => "strong" do -%>
 Hello world!
<% end -%>
```

and if your html is big consider transfering to a partial, hope it elucidates your doubt.

Comment: The question was how is the best approach to build the html string in helpers. Saying that you should put your code in views is not a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to build a longer "safe" html the recommended way is:

```
html = "".html_safe
html.safe_concat "Testing boldfaced char <b>A</b>"
html
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can and should make use of partials in view helpers as well. Having raw html tags outside of views is a code smell that I try to avoid as much as possible.

Related question: [Rails view helpers in helper file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380938/rails-view-helpers-in-helper-file)

Comment: Rail's default helpers ( link_to, form_for, etc ) doesn't have these raw html tags outside of views?

Comment: They might, but that should not deter you from organizing your code better, especially when the framework has features that allow you to do so.