# unescape html render in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, I have a partial that returns some html and replace the contents on a page. but for the life of me I can't get it to unescape the render.

```
>     render(:partial => @partial)
>     => "<table>\n  <tr>\n    <td>\n      <input id=\"target_columns_\" name=\"target_columns[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"id\" />\n     
> <label for=\"id\">Id</label><br />\n      <input
> id=\"target_columns_\" name=\"target_columns[]\" type=\"checkbox\"
> value=\"email\" />\n      <label for=\"email\">Email</label><br />\n  
> </td>\n    <td>\n      <input id=\"target_columns_\"
> name=\"target_columns[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"created_at\" />\n 
> <label for=\"created_at\">Created at</label><br />\n      <input
> id=\"target_columns_\" name=\"target_columns[]\" type=\"checkbox\"
> value=\"updated_at\" />\n      <label for=\"updated_at\">Updated
> at</label><br />\n    </td>\n  </tr>\n</table>\n"
```

i've tried raw, html_safe... nothing seems to work. I just want it to be "" I think. Right now, when I replace it on the page, it actually renders out as text fields for some reason.

heres the JS that replaces the content on the page, and does the render.

```
$("#field-list").html('<%= j(render(:partial => @partial)) %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I stucked in same problem recently and a good approach was building html through `content_tag`.
Please check this topic:

[Helpers in Rails - What's the best approach when building the html string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309338/helpers-in-rails-whats-the-best-approach-when-building-the-html-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
= raw html
```

or:

```
= html.html_safe
```

If you use haml you could give the equivalent `!=` a try

```
!= render(:partial => @partial)
```

instead of

```
= render(:partial => @partial)
```