# Rails - Role of helper file in MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, view-helpers

I have seen some of the gems. They used some view logic in helper file like [Rails view helpers in helper file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380938/rails-view-helpers-in-helper-file). What is the role of helper file in rails. The helper file belongs to view family ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks, A Fader Darkly. It helps me to learn lot.

Comment: If you like my answer, please be so kind as to accept it. If not, I would appreciate it if you would let me know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helper files allow you to move code out of the view (which should look as much like a pure template as possible) and into a place which feels more code-ey. This is good because it helps separate concerns and can promote code reuse across templates.

** WARNING: OPINIONS AHEAD **

However, many people complain about the way helpers have been implemented in Rails. I've grown to see them as sub-optimal as well. Some people even complain about the whole concept of helpers.

They're implemented as modules, which causes problems (with testing for example, or inheritance.)

They can easily become a dumping ground for functionality you can't think of a place for. This is bad because it helps your application become 'calcified' - random distribution of spaghetti code eventually makes even simple changes difficult and dangerous.

It's often better to think of an appropriate object to encapsulate the behaviour and use that.

For a simple application though, helpers can be... Well, helpful.

Comment: Some people use helpers to build HTML fragments, and indeed there are a wealth of objects and methods for helping here. However, I reject this concept utterly. It can produce some utterly convoluted and unclear code, it fully mixes mark-up and logic, and it fragments the mark-up into more than one layer of code. Where it's harder for the front-end developers to get at it. I prefer creating simple data structures (arrays, hashes, structs etc.) and passing them to partials through a facade. (The decorator pattern serves the same purpose in this regard.)

Comment: another feature of helpers is that they are testable.

Comment: It's true that helpers can be seen as units that can be tested individually. However, they have access to the view context which may be difficult to stub - or may bring all of Rails along with it for a general case. It could be argued that finding or creating a class for the functionality to live in (if done well) would lead to fewer dependencies and even cleaner unit tests. (You could even remove the need for Rails to be loaded up at all!) This is all a bit overkill for a small site though.